# Nodejs os.cpus model checking is its intel and which one

Tags: javascript, node.js, cpu

I am using node's

```
os.cpus();
```

This returns model which is what I need to filter.

For example it's return:

```
{ model: 'Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3720QM CPU @ 2.60GHz',
```

What I need to do is to get if it's an intel i3 or higher.

I don't mind using another library for this... I just need a way to check it it's Intel and if it **i3 or higher**.

How can I do this?

Comment: Curious as to why this threshold is significant to you, as a Node.js developer. Is there something an Intel i3 or higher can do in Node.js that other CPUs can't?

Comment: The process that's going to run works better on intels i3 +

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for an external library do do this.
You can just use a [RegEx](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to check if the model is an Intel i *x* cpu:

```
os.cpus().forEach(el => console.log(el.model.match(/Intel(.*)i/)))

// => [ 'Intel(R) Core(TM) i',
//      '(R) Core(TM) ',
//      index: 0,
//      input: 'Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3720QM CPU @ 2.60GHz' ] ....
```

If the result is not `null`, then it is an Intel i3 cpu or higher.

To make a condition on the exact version, you can do it the same way:

```
os.cpus().forEach(el => {
  if (el.model.search('Intel') === 0) {
    console.log(el.model.match(/i(.*)-/)[1])  // => 7
  }
})
```

Comment: Where is the 3 specified?

Comment: As far as I know there is no Intel core before i3 that match that name pattern so no need to specify.

Comment: The problem is that after some changes I'm going to to have to change the min to i7 ... is there a way to specify a minimum number?

Comment: so os.cpus().forEach(el => console.log(el.model.match(/Intel(.*)i7/))) ?

Comment: How can I get this in a condition to return one or the other? Right now it gives me a list

Comment: I updated my answer. I let you make the condition based on the version number.